# Scala - Sealed trait grand child

Tags: scala

While experimenting with sealed traits, I found (to my surprise) that if in one file, I have this code

```
sealed trait Sealed
trait SealedChild extends Sealed
```

And in another file, I have

```
trait SealedGrandchild extends SealedChild
```

Compiling the code succeeds.

Why is it that `SealedGranchild` can be defined even though it has a sealed ancestor type in another file? Other than explicitly declaring `SealedChild` as `sealed`, is there a way to prevent the `SealedChild` from being extended outside the file where it's defined?

Comment: Not marking `SealedChild` as `sealed` is explicitly saying you want to allow extending it in other files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `sealed` modifier only applies to the direct children of `Sealed`, it is not propagated to the whole inheritance tree. Propagating it in alll cases would be very restrictive, so you have to repeat the modifier for each level of the tree you want sealed.